# Post href value to ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
      $.get('data.php', {'page':$(this).attr("data")}, function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
      });                         
    });
 });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```html
<a href="#" data ="ajkdfk">apple</a>
<a href="#"data ="kasnfjk">pear</a>
<a href="#" data ="ankjlfs">banana</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

I want to send value of data attribute of `href tag` to ajax function like `"data=ajkdfk"` and send to this value to data.

PHP page to update it to my database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

Only `data` attribute won't work.  It should be **data-*** where you replace the * with the key you want to use.

And then retrieve the value by using the defined key,

HTML code would look something like this,

```
<a href="#" data-pagename ="ajkdfk">apple</a>
<a href="#"data-pagename ="kasnfjk">pear</a>
<a href="#" data-pagename ="ankjlfs">banana</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Along with following jQuery code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
      var pagenamevalue=$(this).data('pagename');
      $.get('data.php', {'page':pagenamevalue}, function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
      });                         
    });
 });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

We've used jQuery's [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function to access the value by **data-key**.

> **data-*** attributes are used to store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements.

Comment: can we send "data=pagename" value to data.php page and store in database?

Comment: how please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Only data attribute WILL work, but you should use a data-key.

You should add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

before your document.ready [ I hope you are getting $ is not a function ].

It must be like —

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').click(function(){
          var pagenamevalue=$(this).data('pagename');
          $.get('data.php', {'page':pagenamevalue}, function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
          });                         
        });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: I think it sends the "data-pagename" value to data.php page but I want to echo that value in the same page. and my PHP page code is $page = $_GET['pagename'];//$_GET['page'] should be apple or pear or banana
if(isset($page)){
   
   echo $page;}